# Evaluating fitted linear model

Tags: fitting

Apologies if this has been already answered, I have been fitting a linear model on some data and I am struggling to evaluate it later on.

```
Dimensions[trainX]
```

> {2000, 62}

```
Dimensions[trainY]
```

> {2000}

```
fittedModel = LinearModelFit[{trainX,trainY}]
```

> FittedModel[-0.0111841 #1 - 0.0112909 #2 + <<90>> + 3.82331*10^(-8) #62]

```
Dimensions[testX[[1]]]
```

> {62}

```
fittedModel[testX[[1]]]
```

> FittedModel[-0.0111841 #1 - 0.0112909 #2 + <<90>> + 3.82331*10^(-8) #62][{1.16676, 0.857073, 0.680667, 0.5, 0.5, 0.367287, 0.264725, 0.19446, 
>     0.19446, 0.142845, 0.19446, 0.142845, 0.142845, 0.104931, 0.0772179,
>      0.0567222, 0.0567222, 0.0416667, 0.0567222, 0.0416667, 0.0416667, 
>     0.0306072, 0.0567222, 0.0416667, 0.0416667, 0.0306072, 0.0416667, 
>     0.0306072, 0.0306072, 0.0224833, 0.018019, 0.0132363, 0.0132363, 
>     0.00972302, 0.0132363, 0.00972302, 0.00972302, 0.00714227, 
>     0.0132363, 0.00972302, 0.00972302, 0.00714227, 0.00972302, 
>     0.00714227, 0.00714227, 0.00524653, 0.0132363, 0.00972302, 
>     0.00972302, 0.00714227, 0.00972302, 0.00714227, 0.00714227, 
>     0.00524653, 0.00972302, 0.00714227, 0.00714227, 0.00524653, 
>     0.00714227, 0.00524653, 0.00524653, 0.00385396}]

Clearly I was expecting something completely different in that last line. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you attempting to fit a linear model with 62 predictors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written `fittedModel[{x1, x2, ..., x62}]` instead of `fittedModel[x1, x2, ..., x62]`

You can use [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) to evaluate all elements of `testX`

```
fittedModel @@@ testX
(* or *) fittedModel["PredictedResponse"]
```

Or a single element:

```
fittedModel @@ testX[[1]]
```